# how to check of query from database retrieved or cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have following queries from rails logs

1. Called to database

   ```
    Userdetail Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `userdetails`.* FROM `userdetails` WHERE `userdetails`.`user_id` IN (3, 4)
   ```
2. Called to Cache

   ```
   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `userdetails`.* FROM `userdetails` WHERE `userdetails`.`user_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   ```
3. Unknown

   ```
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `votes`.`voter_id` = 3 AND `votes`.`voter_type` = 'User' AND `votes`.`votable_id` = 5690 AND `votes`.`votable_type` = 'Post'
   ```

There is no LOAD or CACHE word indicating the store in type 3

How do I know where this query was performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're doing a count. `CACHE` would have been written anyway if it was sent to the cache, my guess is that it was performed on the DB.

To verify this, you could try to execute the query several times in a row, the subsequent calls should be marked as `CACHE`

Comment: Thanks I think you are right as all such happens only on count query and may be as there is no class object loaded,so rails does not display it.